# Adding Local Storage option in my ToDo List site

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I made my basic ToDo list site after learning react. I wanted to add a function of saving the items on reload. I am a beginner in react so I am facing difficulty in this. I tried the following code:

```
import React from "react";
import ToDoList from "./components/ToDoList";
import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
import '../src/App.css'

export default function TodoInput() {

  const saveLocalTasks = () => {
    let savedTasks = localStorage.getItem('tasks')
    console.log(savedTasks)

    if (savedTasks) {
      return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'))
    } else {
      return []
    }
  }

  const [task, setTask] = React.useState('')
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0)
  const [taskList, setTaskList] = React.useState([saveLocalTasks()])
  const [disable, setDisable] = React.useState(true)

  
  const [viewTaskList, setViewTaskList] = React.useState(true)
  
  const updateTaskList = () => {
    setTaskList([...taskList, {object: task, key: Date.now()}])
    setTask('')
    setViewTaskList(false)
    setCount(count + 1)
    setDisable(true)
  }
  
  const inputValue = e => {
      setTask(e.target.value)

      e.target.value === '' || task === '' || task.length === 0
      ?
      setDisable(true)
      :
      setDisable(false)
  }
  // console.log(task.length)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(taskList.object))
  }, [taskList])

    return (
      <div>
          <Navbar />
          <header>
            <div className="todolist-border">
                <div className="todo-input-form">
                    <input
                    className = "inputText" 
                    placeholder="Add a Task" 
                    value={task} 
                    onChange = {inputValue}
                    />
                    <button disabled = {disable} onClick = {updateTaskList} className="todo-add-button">+</button>
                </div>
                {
                  viewTaskList || count === 0
                  ?
                  <div className="pendingTasks-div">
                      <img className = "pending-task-image" 
                      src= "https://dm0qx8t0i9gc9.cloudfront.net/watermarks/image/rDtN98Qoishumwih/task-pending-cartoon-business-vector-illustrations_zJCs81OO_SB_PM.jpg"
                      alt="pending-tasks" />
                      <p className="no-task-message">There are no pending tasks!! #Enjoy</p>
                  </div>
                  :
                  <ToDoList count = {count} setCount = {setCount} task = {task} taskList = {taskList} setTaskList = {setTaskList}/>
                }
            </div>
          </header>
      </div>
    )
}
```

But the following error is coming up:
[image]

The following is the code for ToDoList component:

```
import React from "react";

export default function ToDoList(props) {

    const deleteTaskListItem = (key) => {
        const updatedList = props.taskList.filter((item) => {
            return (
                item.key !== key
            )
        })
        props.setTaskList(updatedList)
        props.setCount(props.count - 1)
    }
    

    return(
        <div>
            {props.taskList.map((item) => {
                return (
                <div key = {item.key} className="todolist-div">
                    <input type="checkbox" className="list-checkbox">
                    </input>
                    <p>{item.object}</p>
                    <button onClick={()=>deleteTaskListItem(item.key)} className="delete-button">X</button>
                </div>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Kindly suggest a method to add this feature.

Answer (score 0):

The above error happens when you try to JSON.parse `undefined`. Check this [link](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-unexpected-token-u-in-json-at-position-0#:%7E:text=The%20%22Unexpected%20token%20u%20in,JSON%20string%20before%20parsing%20it.). Here, I tried to do some changes in your code on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-silence-12b9ip?file=/src/TodoInput.jsx:63-2837). There you can find some changes I have made.

- Firstly, you shouldn't try to set data in this useState `const [taskList, setTaskList] = React.useState([saveLocalTasks()])`. You should set data in `useEffect`.
- In the following code, you are trying to save `taskList.object` but `taskList` is an array. The below code will throw an error.

  ```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(taskList.object))
  }, [taskList])
  ```
- As you asked in your question, you want to try to save data when the user reloads the window. You can achieve this by using `window.onbeforeunload` event (line 48).

Hope the above will help you.

P.S: The codesandbox code I shared isn't fully functional. I have made just some changes that will help you to go ahead with your coding. Thank you.